# sbt run fails in this trivial example

Tags: sbt

This is a minimal example to show a very weird thing when using `sbt run`. Trying to make the example any smaller, then the problem does not arises any more. Am I missing something or is this a bug or `sbt`?

build.sbt

```
name := "testsbt"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

project/build.properties

```
sbt.version = 0.13.13
```

src/main/scala/application/Test.scala

```
package application

import java.io._

case class Page(items: List[Item])
case class Item(text: String)

object Test extends App {
    val page = Page(List(Item("item1")))

    val filename = "./page.obj"

    val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename))
    try oos.writeObject(page)
    finally oos.close()

    println("read: " + new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)).readObject())
}
```

executing this with sbt run fails:

```
$ sbt run 
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field application.Page.items of type scala.collection.immutable.List in instance of application.Page
```

however, executing sbt package and running from it works:

```
$ sbt package
$ scala -cp target/scala-2.11/testsbt_2.11-1.0.jar application.Test
read: Page(List(Item(item1)))
```

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug. Does it reproduce if you build on the commandline with `scalac`?

Comment: it works by building with `scalac` and running it with `scala`. it also works by building it with `sbt packagev, and running it with `scala`. the only time where it does not work is when run with `sbt run`.